# How to make Symfony2 DIC to call Doctrine\ORM\Configuration#setHydrationCacheImpl()

Tags: caching, symfony, doctrine-orm

As of newer version of Doctrine2, I know there is `Doctrine\ORM\Configuration#setHydrationCacheImpl()`
to pass such as MemcacheCache, etc.

But how can it be done in container?

I'm using two entity_manager: named "default" and "other".

I first tried defining hydration_cache into config.yml like

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        ...
        entity_managers:
            default:
                ...
                metadata_cache_driver:
                    type: service
                    id: memcache_driver
                ...
                hydration_cache_driver:
                    type: service
                    id: memcache_driver
                ...
            other:
                ...
```

note: where `memcache_driver` is defined by me, instanceof `Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache`

then I got `Unrecognized options "hydration_cache_driver" under "doctrine.orm.entity_managers.default"`.

I also tried to directly tweak container in AppKernel#buildContainer,
but there's no instances of \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration defined as service,
so I couldn't retrieve the Configuration instance.

Any suggestions are welcome.

EDIT:

I'm sure that there is feature for caching hydrated object is re-implemented as of Doctrine 2.2.2.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1766

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.2.2/tests/Doctrine/Tests/ORM/Functional/HydrationCacheTest.php?source=c

For other simple services, I can easily add methods to call by overwriting whole definitions like

```
service1:
    ...
    calls:
        [method calls]
```

but for the entity_manager, I'm not sure how to add method calls to them.

So my question in other words, how to configure orm at lower level like without using semantic configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, as hydration cache is hardly used,
so I decided this time to call Query#setHydrationCacheProfile just before each query is executed.

```
...
$query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
$cache = $this->container->get('...'); //instanceof MemcacheCache
$query->setHydrationCacheProfile(new CacheProfile(null, null $cache));
$query->execute();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option "hydration_cache_driver", you should use "result_cache_driver" to achieve that.

From Doctrine 2.1, Doctrine can cache results of the queries, but it doesn't cache objects after hydration.

Look at doc about doctrine configuration:

http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, it's disabled once, but re-implemented as hydration cache as of 2.2.2. See my edit.